# Angularjs - how to watch for changes in DOM and apply a new style to it?

Tags: angularjs

I have a very simple angular app that pushes data in without refreshing the page using setInterval. Now, how can I listen or watch for new data/changes, so that if the new value/data differ from the previous one a new css style will be applied to that particular new value (for example it will change the font color to red).

My code is below:

view:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="friend in friends"><strong>Name: </strong>{{friend.name}} : {{friend.username}}</li>
        </ul>
```

data:

```
angular
    .module ('myApp')
    .factory ('Friends', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            get: function () {
                return $http.get ('users.json').then (function (response) {  
                    return response.data;
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Controller:

```
angular
    .module ('myApp')
    .controller ('summaryCtrl', ['$scope', 'Friends', function ($scope, Friends) {
        $scope.title = "Friends";
        $scope.loadData = function () {
            Friends.get ().then (function (data) {
                $scope.friends = data;
            });
        };

        //initial load
        $scope.loadData();

        var timer = setInterval(function(){
            $scope.loadData();

        },5000);

    }]);
```

many thanks

Comment: Use $interval instead of setInterval, it will trigger a digest loop

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do a diff. I'd recommend discarding the notion of check the DOM entirely; it's purely a display layer. Instead  focus purely on the data and figure out how to flag which entries have changed. The DOM should render red text based on the flags.

Comment: Try `$scope.$apply();` after `$scope.loadData();`

Comment: Both @Edminsson and Umidbek Karimov's answers are correct. Both should be phrased as answers below so they can be voted on and one might get marked "best answer". Answers are more helpful than comments because SO will treat them differently (for example, you can see how many answers there are in the list of questions).

Comment: Thanks guys for your answer. Any idea how to put it together so that the red color will be applied to the change? I'm very new to angular :(

Answer (score 3):

Use $interval instead of setInterval, since it triggers a digest loop it will update your data  automatically

```
angular
    .module ('myApp')
    .controller ('summaryCtrl', ['$scope', 'Friends', '$interval' function ($scope, Friends, $interval) {
        $scope.title = "Friends";
        $scope.loadData = function () {
            Friends.get ().then (function (data) {
                $scope.friends = data;
            });
        };

        //initial load
        $scope.loadData();

        var timer = $interval(function(){
            $scope.loadData();

        },5000);

    }]);
```

Comment: cool, many thanks....what about applying the css style when there is a different value to the old value?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to manually compare each friend item and assign a `changeFlag` whenever the data has changed.

To start, keep a reference to the old data and whenever new data comes in, compare the two, like this:

```
var oldData = undefined; // Somewhere in initialization.
...
Friends.get().then(function (response) {
    var newData = response;
    if (oldData && JSON.stringify(oldData) != JSON.stringify(newData))
    {
        $scope.friends = newData;
        $scope.$apply(); // Force the entire page to be redrawn. You can do style bindings to change a style.
    }
    oldData = response;
}
```

This will get you half-way to your goal. You will only be refreshing the page whenever something has changed, but there is no indication as to **which** friend has changed. I imagine this is what you are attempting to accomplish. You want to highlight those friends that have changed.

To do this we could simply create a comparison function that applies a flag to each object that has changed. However, this code assumes that **some property** on each friend remains fixed. This is normally why an `id` property is given to each item in a database. I'm going to assume you have an `id` property for each friend that never changes regardless if their name, age, email, etc. does.

```
var changeFlagFriendsObjects = function(oldData, newData) {
    var idToOldDataMap = {};
    oldData.forEach(function (friend) {
       idToOldDataMap[friend.id] = friend;
    });

    newData.forEach(function (friend) {
        var oldFriendData = idToOldDataMap[friend.id];
        friend.changeFlag = JSON.stringify(oldFriendData) != JSON.stringify(friend);             
    });
};

// You would call changeFlagFriendsObjects in the other example above. I'm sure this would be easy to figure out how to place.
```

Regarding binding styles in the HTML to properties, see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle).

An example would be like the following:

```
<!-- Apply the 'highlight' style when changeFlag is true -->
<li ng-repeat="friend in friends" ng-style="highlight={changeFlag: true}"><strong>Name: </strong>{{friend.name}} : {{friend.username}}</li>
```

Comment: wow, this looks promising. Although I was reading in some article that this can be achieved by using $watch and $apply..is that true? I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with $watch, but my recommendation would not be to do a $watch of each friend object because I can guarantee that watching each object is going to incur a lot of overhead compared to what is above. The nice part of what I have written is that you have full control on what and when each friend object gets updated.